# Can we tag answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Can we tag answers with tags, not just the questions?  Especially on this site where multiple answers may be good, and none are necessarily best, just most popular, it might be worthwhile to tag the answers themselves.

For example, we often make distinctions between "functional programming weenies" and "dynamic programming zealots" in causal conversation, when it's clear that an answer has a particular bias, it might make sense to tag it.

There could be good usability in searching for questions for these tags to answer meta-questions like "what types of questions have good functional programming solutions"?

Comment: [functional-programming-weenie] would be a meta-tag anyway, and thus discouraged. To say nothing of the purely pejorative usage scenario...

Answer (score 5):

Answers inherit the tags from the questions. If an answer doesn't match at least one of the tags in the question, it may be an indication that it doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 3):

This was discussed before for other sites and declined. I don't see any reason to implement this feature here. If we need tags on answers it means that something is wrong with the question and if this is an issue with many questions it's a problem of the whole community.

Comment: I agree for 'objective' questions/answers there is no need, but for subjective ones, I believe there's a case to be made.  Simply saying 'discussed before' isn't suitable.  I did search for this and could not find it on the other sites.  Do you have a URL?